# Cannot get hyperlink from winword document: TYPE MISMATCH

Tags: c++, ms-word, hyperlink, enumerate, comaddin

I have the following code in my COM Add-In for MS Office to go through all hyperlinks in winword document and then parse them:

```
...
HRESULT hr;
ULONG nRet;

CComQIPtr<MSWORD::Hyperlinks> hylinks = doc->Hyperlinks; // CComQIPtr<_Document> doc
ATLASSERT(hylinks);

IEnumVARIANTPtr pEnum = hylinks->Get_NewEnum(); 

for (int i = 1; i <= hylinks->Count; i++)
{
    VARIANT v = {};
    hr = pEnum->Next(1, &v, &nRet);
    if (FAILED(hr)) continue;

    CComQIPtr<MSWORD::Hyperlink> link;
    ATLASSERT(link);

    hr = hylinks->raw_Item(&v, &link);
    if (FAILED(hr)) continue;
    ...
    // parse hyperlink's address
}
...
```

The result (hr) when raw_Item() is called, is 80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)). And there is no trouble with code like this one when I go through Shapes.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Unfortunately, the "winword" format is not a publicly available standard. So I guess you'll have to ask MS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found out. How many collections have office application, so many ways to iterate them. Here we can do it like following, assign index of type VARIANT manually, not with enumerator:

```
CComQIPtr<MSWORD::Hyperlinks> hylinks = doc->Hyperlinks;  // CComQIPtr<_Document> doc
ATLASSERT(hylinks);

for (int i = 1; i <= hylinks->Count; i++)
{
    VARIANT ind;
    ind.iVal = i;
    ind.vt = VT_I2;

    CComQIPtr<MSWORD::Hyperlink> link;
    ATLASSERT(link);
    link = hylinks->Item(&ind);
    
    // do your magic
}
```